# Logs not storing correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to log each users activity using their API Key. It is storing the logs, however it is not storing which user has committed that log.

I have a log class:

```
public class Log
{
    [Key] 
    public int logID { get; set; }
    public string logString { get; set; }
    public string logDateTime { get; set; }

    public Log() { }       
}
```

And a user class which has an ICollection of Logs:

public class User

```
  { 
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }  //unique database key and API key for user

        public ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }

        public User() { }
    }
```

This is the method which is called when the user does an activity:

```
 public void addLogToUserWithApiKey(string logMessage, string apiKey)
    {
        Log newLog = new Log();
        newLog.logID = makeLogID();
        newLog.logString = logMessage;
        newLog.logDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");

        using (var context = new UserContext())
        {
            User logUser = checkIfUserExistsWithApiKeyandReturnUser(apiKey);
            if (logUser.Logs == null)
            {
                logUser.Logs = new Collection<Log>();

            }
            logUser.Logs.Add(newLog);

            logUser.Logs.Add(newLog);
            context.Logs.Add(newLog);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The logs and users have separate tables. Currently, the log table is storing the log id, message and datetime however the API key is null.

Please can someone explain to me where I have gone wrong?

[image: This is how the Logs table looks]

Comment: Shouldn't your `Log` class have a property called ApiKey?

Comment: `ApiKey` is null where? `Log` table? `User` table? `addLogToUserWithApiKey()` method? I don't understand the schema. It looks like you're just adding logs for users, in which case shouldn't `ApiKey` already be set for the user? Unclear what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry API Key is null in the log table!

Comment: Your `Log` class needs to have a property of `ApiKey`, and you need to set it with the user's key.